# Can't run exec('ffmpeg'); ffmpeg, wamp & windows 2008 server

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

i've installed FFMPEG on my windows server. If i go to cmd and type ffmpeg -version i get the version, available commands etc. I use WAMP server with php 5.4.12

The reason i am not using ffmpeg-php is because i have installed it with no errors and i cant use the extension for php even tho it says it is installed.

When i try to do

```
<?php
echo exec('ffmpeg -version'); 
?>
```

its totally blank, no errors or nothing.

If i run

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami'); 
?>
```

i get : nt authority\system

So i can run exec in my php.

I've also tried the same with shell_exec(); ffmpeg not working with either of them.

After looking at other stackoverflow questions i've seen people fixing this problem by allowing IIS user to use ffmpeg.exe. But i am using Wamp so i don't know what to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will get a blank output if the result of the command was erroneous or failed. It makes debugging difficult. I recommend Nicholas Walker's approach below, it fixed the problem for me. See my comments, hopefully they help (then again this was 3 years ago now, I doubt you're still having this problem...)

Answer (score 3):

Managed to fix it by typing the path to ffmpeg.exe before the command:

```
<?php
echo exec('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -version');
?>
```

Comment: Despite adding ffmpeg to my PATH vars in windows, you appear to need to give the directory of ffmpeg. I recommend this solution for users struggling despite adding ffmpeg to PATH.

Comment: I found the extra 'ffmpeg' in the command seems to cause problems on some systems. My implmentation works with: `shell_exec('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -version');`

Answer (score 1):

Add the path of **ffmpeg.exe** file to WINDOWS Environment Variables. 
In SYSTEM VARIABLES, edit the PATH adding this at the end (e.g.):

```
;C:\ffmpeg\bin\
```

Otherwise, you always have to point the path in EXEC.

Comment: I've actually done this (in order to make ffmpeg available from any folder), it doesn't actually work. Nicolas Walker's approach strangely seems to work...